# Show if disk or partition is BIOS bootable or UEFI bootable

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I have a pen drive or disk and it's reachable under

```
/dev/sda
```

and the partitions are under

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda...
```

I want to know for the disk itself and for each partition:

- is it classical bootable (BIOS boot mode/before UEFI) (I think an MBR is used)
- is it UEFI bootable (I think no MBR is used then)
- none of above
- both of above

I know there is fdisk but it does not support GPT so I cannot use it for GPT disks. And parted only shows "boot" flag but it does not tell if it's BIOS bootable or UEFI bootable.

I know the task can't be so hard because every modern BIOS can list the bootable devices and it also shows if it's UEFI or not.

Comment: I wrote a 'first answer' but have also a question: Do you want a general method, or do you want to know about some particular Linux distro, some particular tool or method that makes bootable drives, or is there a particular drive, that you have problems to boot? -- By the way, new versions of fdisk can manage drives with GPT.

Comment: @sudodus I am looking for a general way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A disk is bootable BIOS-style if the two last bytes of its first 512-byte block (block #0) are 0x55 and 0xaa. If that is true, then a BIOS firmware will assume that block contains a valid Master Boot Record (MBR) and will attempt to execute it. The first 446 or so bytes should contain executable code for x86 processors in 16-bit 8086-compatible mode.

```
# dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -t x1z -A x | tail -2
0001f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  >..............U.<
000200
```

Anything beyond that will depend on what the MBR code does: most standard Microsoft MBRs will look for a primary partition that has been flagged as active, and will continue by loading and executing the first block of that partition. But another bootloader like GRUB is free to completely ignore the partition flags and do something completely different if desired.

---

A removable media is bootable UEFI-style if it contains a filesystem that is recognizable to the UEFI firmware (the specification originally mandated a particular version of FAT32, but it was expanded to cover FAT12 and FAT16 too; also, firmware implementations are free to add support for other filesystem types), the filesystem has a directory named `EFI` (case-insensitive), that directory has a sub-directory named `boot`, and that sub-directory has a bootloader file (`*.efi`) with a name specific to the system architecture. Or in other words, as expressed in Windows-style absolute paths starting from the root of that particular filesystem:

- `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi` for 64-bit x86 systems
- `\EFI\boot\bootia32.efi` for 32-bit x86 systems (some mini-laptops and old x86 Macs)
- `\EFI\boot\bootia64.efi` for Intel Itanium systems (mostly servers running either some versions of Windows, HP-UX or OpenVMS)
- `\EFI\boot\bootarm.efi` for 32-bit ARM processors with UEFI firmware
- `\EFI\boot\bootaa64.efi` for 64-bit ARM processors with UEFI firmware
- `\EFI\boot\bootriscvNN.efi` for 32-, 64- and 128-bit RISC-V processors with UEFI firmware (`NN` can be 32, 64 or 128, respectively)
- ...and this list can be expanded as UEFI firmware is implemented for new processor architectures.

If the disk has a GPT partition table, the partition containing the UEFI bootloader(s) is expected to have a partition type GUID of `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`, identifying it as a *EFI System Partition*, or ESP for short. Any system with UEFI firmware should support GPT partitioning.

If the disk has a MBR partition table, the partition containing the UEFI bootloader(s) should have a MBR partition type code of `0xef`... but this is not a strict requirement.

Non-removable disks can have other UEFI bootloaders in different paths, as the bootloader pathname of an installed OS will be stored in the same non-volatile memory that is used to hold other UEFI firmware settings. Those should be placed in the ESP partition, in a vendor-specific sub-directory of the `\EFI` directory. Use `efibootmgr -v` as root in Linux to see the UEFI bootloader pathnames and associated boot settings.

A non-removable disk can also have a UEFI bootloader file in one of the fixed paths specified above for removable media: this is then called a *fallback bootloader path* and can be used if the non-volatile memory settings have been lost. Windows places a copy of its `bootmgfw.efi` like this by default; Linux distributions' installers generally won't do this unless you specifically request it.

As ESP is often (but not always) mounted at `/boot/efi/` in Linux, you'll find e.g. RHEL's Secure Boot shim bootloader at `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/shimx64.efi` and the actual GRUB at `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grubx64.efi`. The first `efi` is simply the name of the mount-point directory, and the second `EFI` is the name of the sub-directory required by the UEFI specification.

---

According to the GPT specification, a GPT partition table starts at disk block #1, and block #0 is reserved for a *protective MBR*: a dummy MBR partition table that is supposed to have only a single partition entry, describing a partition that occupies the whole disk (or the MBR absolute maximum of about 2 TiB, whichever is smaller), with partition type set to `0xee`.

This tells systems that don't support GPT "yes, this disk has been formatted and partitioned and is in use, and no, it is not a partition type you would know anything about. **Please don't** offer the user an easy way to one-click-format me."

Of course this makes it possible to construct a disk with *hybrid GPT/MBR partitioning*: a valid MBR (potentially including boot code) for systems that won't understand GPT, and a valid GPT partition table for those who do, with an ESP partition containing any number of UEFI bootloaders for different system architectures.

Comment: Is the MBR always at the beginning of the disk or can partitions also have a MBR?

Comment: Partitions can have PBR, which corresponds to MBR, and the PBR can be activated via chainloading (from a bootloader that was originally booted via an MBR in the same or another drive).

Comment: MBR is, by definition, block #0 or in other words, the very first block of the disk. As @sudodus said, the first block of each partition is known as PBR. But if a partition has been presented as a virtual disk to a virtual machine, then the VM would see the partition as a whole disk and thus would treat its first block as its MBR. This would generate a nested partition structure that can be awkward to access without the use of the VM that created it in the first place (I've had to rescue some data from a setup like this.)

Comment: I want to add that all Windows formatted and also GPT formatted disks have 0x55 0xAA at the end of the first 512 bytes. Even if they're not made for booting. I think your answer is correct but 0x55 0xAA says nothing.

Comment: @zomega If those "not made for booting" MBRs with 0x55 0xAA don't cause a legacy BIOS to hang, that means they **must** have some valid code in their first 446 bytes. Often such code will check for the existence of active partitions on the current disk and exit if there is none, or outright print out a text like "This disk is not bootable" and exit. But as far as BIOS is concerned, executing that little bit of program *is* indistinguishable from an actual boot attempt.

Comment: @telcoM Well it's not completely indistinguishable if you have a list of known bootstraps. For example if you find a FAT32 bootstrap you can check if there is a bootable partitions in the partition table. I hope you know what I mean...

Comment: @zomega "We" can check, but the BIOS won't. My point is, a classic PC BIOS doesn't compare the MBR to "a list of known bootstraps". It just loads the MBR into memory, looks for 0x55 0xAA at the end, and if it's there, jumps right into the beginning of it in an attempt to execute it. If there is no valid program code in the MBR, this will crash the system, so there *must* be some valid code that either just returns control to the BIOS or continues the boot process in some way - either by checking for active primary partition, or by doing something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

From [BootRepair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), run the ***boot-info script* without making any automatic repair**, and you should get information about the boot structure of the drive (and other drives too).

The boot-info script might fail, if the boot structure is too different from that of Ubuntu. Then you should check if there is an EFI system partition (ESP) with a FAT file system and with GPT if there is a very small partition with a 'bios_grub' flag. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) for more details. Things can be rather different between bootable drives of different operating systems and for example cloned hybrid iso files.

For this reason it is probably best to test it in a computer, that you know can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy boot).

Comment: Test in a computer that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS modes **and allows you to control which mode it uses.** Some systems unfortunately provide limited or no boot mode controls in the firmware setup menus ("BIOS setup"). Without useful controls, you may be at the mercy of the programmed-in defaults. Some of such systems will favor BIOS-style boot, others will favor UEFI; sometimes the vendor which policy that particular system follows! (Yes, I'm somewhat bitter.)